# m3u8 format is not streaming on google tv android 3.1

Tags: android

i tried to play m3u8 in google tv device android version 3.1. is it possible to play m3u8 in google tv without using third party tools?

Thanks in advance

Comment: when i try to play m3u8(live streaming) in tablet, it is working fine but in google tv it is not streaming.simply blank screen.